# Linux: Is there a IPv6 equivalent to the IPv4 kernel option accept_local?

Tags: linux, kernel, routing, ipv6

Since linux kernel >= 2.6.33 the kernel option "accept_local" can be modified:

> `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/${interfaceID}/`
>
> `accept_local` - BOOLEAN
>
> Accept packets with local source addresses. In combination with
>       suitable routing, this can be used to direct packets between two
>       local interfaces over the wire and have them accepted properly.
>       default FALSE

Is there any IPv6 equivalent to this option? If not, is there a patch or plans to implement it in the near future?

Edit: I am using two WIFI Interfaces and have created propper routing rules, which allow me to send packets between these local interfaces over WIFI (no loop-device). I could add routing rules for IPv6 but without this option packets will be dropped as "martian packets". Packets are only accepted, when this boolean is TRUE.

Comment: I would guess it is obsoleted with IPv6 scope support.

Comment: Perhaps you can explain better what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you've made a homebrew wireless bridge that sort of works with IPv4, and now you want to run IPv6 across it. Unfortunately you can't. If this is what you're trying to do, what you need to do is set up a proper WDS. (Wireless Distribution System) The Internet has various howto documents explaining how to do this; here's [one example of such a howto](http://www.tummy.com/journals/entries/jafo_20041220_000528).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, these are the only options available to you under /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf:

http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Linux+IPv6-HOWTO/proc-sys-net-ipv6..html